# How to use ng-repeat in expandable table rows

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to accomplish expanding table rows.

The format for doing this is:

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
  <td>one</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="hiddenRow">
  <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead><tr><td>Test for row one</td></tr></thead>
     <tbody><tr><td>Testing</td></tr></tbody>
    <table>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How can I do ng-repeat over the entire block listed above?

I tried doing

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in colors track by $index" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1{{$index}}" class="accordion-toggle">
  <td>one</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in colors track by $index">
  <td class="hiddenRow">
  <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1{{$index}}">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead><tr><td>Test for row one</td></tr></thead>
     <tbody><tr><td>Testing</td></tr></tbody>
    <table>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But this way the rows don't expand right under the one that is clicked. Also, I'm having to do two loops. How can I do this all in one loop?

Comment: Look at `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Hey, can you create a fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: You are mixing jquery with Angular directive. Better to to use animation and css3 to create your affect.

Answer (score 4):

To iterate over both `<tr>` tags, use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="x in colors track by $index" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1{{$index}}" class="accordion-toggle">
  <td>one</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
  <td class="hiddenRow">
  <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1{{$index}}">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead><tr><td>Test for row one</td></tr></thead>
     <tbody><tr><td>Testing</td></tr></tbody>
    <table>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

A good guide to ng-repeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` work great!

I complemented with angular code for hide/show accordion instead of data-toggle/data target to toggle a css:

```
ng-repeat-start="customer in customers track by $index" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'open' : toggle}"
```

where

```
$scope.toggle = 'open';
```